# Using .map() to display multiple images in an ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, image

How do I display multiple images from an image collection using `.map()`?

```
// Create clipping function
var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry);
};

// Load image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GQ').map(clipper);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(m) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .filterBounds(geometry)  
                    .median()
                    .set('month', m);
}));

// Create a visualization color scheme
var medVis = {
  min: 0, 
  max: 8000,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};


var display = function(image){
  return Map.addLayer(image,medVis);
};

byMonth.map(display);
```

I get the following errors when I run the last few lines of code (please use any geometry of your choice): Please reopen the question as a user has a more relevant answer.

```
Can't encode an undefined value.

Layer 2: Layer error: Failed to decode JSON.
Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.

Layer 3: Layer error: Failed to decode JSON.
Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code? `months` and `modis` are not defined above.

Comment: @JepsonNomad Done!

Comment: I don't think the related answer is exactly what you need. Of course it helps to understand concepts. Here is a code you can use: https://code.earthengine.google.com/94ce0ce2ccfd75ef3fba81653d65c85f. If the question is reopened, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo! How do I re-open the question? @RodrigoE.Principe

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe I also noticed that using `require` and importing your functions takes a bit of time. GEE gets stuck for a bit. Is this normal?

Comment: Importing the module should not take time, what does take time is adding each image from an image collection to the map.. because it's a client-side job